# Distributing .NET 4.0 redistributable with application

Tags: .net, redistributable

I want to pack the .NET 4.0 redistributable with our application.  We will be installing onto systems that may not have external network or Internet access.

I went to the Microsoft site to download this and the redistributable package is listed as 48MB in size.  I always thought it was close to 1GB in size.  I am looking at the wrong thing?

Here is the link I used.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718

I need something that I can install on any qualifying Windows platform and have it perform a complete install of the .NET 4.0 framework without any Internet access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the correct download.  The full .NET 4 framework is less than 50MB.  In addition, if you're sticking to the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx), you can use [this installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872) instead, which is even smaller.

Comment: Okay, what baffles me is why when I go to install my application and the install for the .NET 4.0 framework comes up it says that it needs 1.6GB of disk space.  I know all about compression, but how can a 48MB executable expand into 1.6GB?

Comment: @WPFNewbie: I don't know - you can contact MS support for details, but..> I suspect this is partially due to the fact that it needs to make temporary copies of a lot of system files that will get replaced.  As such, a small file may require a lot of extra working space *during the install*.  It also, I believe, may be doing some ngen compilation on the IL distributed as the installer.  Granted, I have no idea what happens, so this is just speculation...

Comment: @WPFNewbie: That being said, the 50MB .NET 4 installer is the complete, standalone installation.

Comment: (Remember, it says it needs the disk space, not that the entire thing will be used up when it's done ;) )

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Now I can just figure out why my setup package still wants to get it from the Internet it'd be great.

Answer (score -1):

1 Gb! No way man :) This one is the rigth one.

Comment: Should this be considered as an answer?

Comment: @Desolator: Having in mind that the answer has like 3 year and 0 downvotes I will  take the risk :) Thanks for caring anyway.